# java- How to take out json data from string

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

this is my json string for example :

```
{"data":{ "name":"Red Sox win 7-0!","famil":"INSERT TITLE HERE","tel":"2251472"}}
```

this is the code I write but it couldn't get the values:

```
        JSONObject jsons = new JSONObject(myString);
        Iterator<?> keys = jsons.keys();
        String out = "";
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            out += key + ": " + jsons.getString(key) + "\n";
        }
```

How can I get each item's value ?

Comment: the problem with your code, is that keys() returns also data as key

Comment: @Blackbelt I had a problem on my question, I update my new json data , Could you check it out  ?

Answer (score 2):

try this code.

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(myString);

    JSONObject objectData = object.getJSONObject("data");

    String strTel = objectData .optString("tel");
    String strFamil = objectData .optString("famil");
    String strName = objectData .optString("name");
```

Comment: I had a problem on my question, I update my new json data , Could you check it out  ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use `jsons.getString(key)` for each key because your JSONObject contains only Strings.

But in general, JSONObject can contain values of different types: integer, boolean, int/long, double JSONArray and  JSONObject. You have to use the right `.getSomething()` for each one or generat `.get()` that retuns `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Great example [json-simple-example-read-and-write-json](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Comment: I had a problem on my question, I update my new json data , Could you check it out ?